# I cannot get my Jupyter Notebook to recognise the following Pandas Module 'from pandas.io.wb import download

Tags: pandas

My Jupyter notebook doesn't recognise 'from pandas.io.wb import download'

I have downloaded Pandas-datareader, however, when I enter 'from Pandas.io.wb import download' into my Jupyter Notebook, I get the following:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 download()

NameError: name 'download' is not defined

Can anyone assist, this seems to be a common problem from what I'm reading?

Comment: Have you pip installed the`pip install pandas-datareader`

Comment: Hi, yes I ve used Anaconda Prompt and downloaded using 'pip install pandas-datareader' 
Unfortunately, I'm getting the following ModuleNotFoundError: